# How evil is this foreach C macro?

Tags: c, macros, hashtable, c-preprocessor

The preface to this question is that, I realize **C** macros are a touchy subject.  Many time they can be accomplished by a non-macro solution that is more secure and not subject to classic problems like incremented arguments;  so with that out of the way,  I have a hash table implementation in **C** with linked nodes for collision.  I'm sure most have seen this a million times but it goes a bit like this.

```
typedef struct tnode_t {
    char* key; void* value; struct tnode_t* next;
} tnode_t;

typedef struct table_t {
    tnode_t** nodes;
    unsigned long node_count;
    unsigned long iterator; // see macro below
        ...
}
```

I would like to provide an abstracted way of iterating through the nodes.  I considered using a function which takes a function pointer and applies the function to each node but I often find this kind of solution very limiting so I came up with this macro:

```
#define tbleach(table, node) \
    for(node=table->nodes[table->iterator=0];\
        table->iterator<table->node_count;\
        node=node?node->next:table->nodes[++table->iterator])\
            if (node)
```

Which can be used like:

```
tnode_t* n;
tbleach(mytable, n) {
    do_stuff_to(n->key, n->value);
}
```

The only downside I can see is that the iterator index is a part of the table so obviously you could not have two loops going on at the same time in the same table. I am not sure how to resolve this but I don't see it as a deal breaker considering how useful this little macro would be.  So my question.

** *updated* **

I incorporated Zack and Jens's suggestion, removing the problem with "else" and declaring the iterator inside the for statement.  Everything appears to work but visual studio complains that "type name is not allowed" where the macro is used.  I am wondering what exactly happens here because it compiles and runs but I am not sure where the iterator is scoped.

```
#define tbleach(table, node) \
    for(node=table->nodes[0], unsigned long i=0;\
        i<table->node_count;\
        node=node?node->next:table->nodes[++i])\
        if (!node) {} else
```

**Is this approach bad form and if not is there any way to improve it?**

Comment: I can't help but picture Dr. Evil.  "Is it an evil macro?"

Comment: Couldn't you pass the iterator into the macro too? E.g: tbleach( mytable, iterator, n)... That would allow you to have multiple loops running.

Comment: Do you have something against passing a third parameter to use as an iterator?

Comment: Is your hash table's actual table that optimally packed? I thought that they commonly are accessed based on a hash, so they're not at all filled in sequence from 0..n. Also, iterator is only increased when you stop following next-links, but still compared against node_count which seems fishy.

Comment: @unwind Testing has shown that the packing is about 1 in 3 nodes so while not bleeding edge optimized we're going pretty quick.  As for naming the node_count, there is another value in the table stuct for value_count.  naming could be better but that's another topic.

Answer (score 7):

The only really *unacceptable* thing in there is what you already said -- the iterator is part of the table.  You should pull that out like so:

```
typedef unsigned long table_iterator_t;
#define tbleach(table, iter, node) \
    for ((iter) = 0, (node) = (table)->nodes[(iter)]; \
         (iter) < (table)->node_count; \
         (node) = ((node) && (node)->next) \
                  ? (node)->next : (table)->nodes[++(iter)])

// use:
table_iterator_t i;
tnode_t *n;
tbleach(mytable, i, n) {
    do_stuff_to(n->key, n->value);
}
```

I also sucked the `if` statement into the for-loop expresssions because it's slightly safer that way (weird things will not happen if the next token after the close brace of the loop body is `else`).  Note that the array entry `table->nodes[table->node_count]` *will* be read from, unlike the usual convention, so you need to allocate space for it (and make sure it's always NULL).  This was true with your version as well, I think.

EDIT: Corrected logic for case where a table entry is NULL.

Comment: Highly stateful variables like that are a surefire way to get in trouble, if threads are anywhere in your periphery.

Comment: I just realized I had a bug - if an entry in `table->nodes` is null, it'll crash.  Gotta check both `node` and `node->next` in the loop-advance expression.  This is approaching the point where some inline helper functions might be a good idea.

Comment: Won't you still have cases where n is null inside the loop if a table entry has no nodes in it?

Comment: Mm, yes, if there are two NULL table entries in a row.  That'd be a reason to go back to the nested `if` statement, or (my preference) pull the loop-advance expression out to an inline helper so it can be more sophisticated.

Comment: Yeah after trying this I found that out - my KISSy solution was simply to do this: if (!node) {} else

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Zack's answer about the iterator and about the terminating `if` that may obfuscate the syntax:

If you have C99, use local variables in the for loop. This will avoid bad surprises of variables of the surrounding scope that will hold dangling pointers. Use something like this inside the macro:

```
for(nodeS node = ...
```

And, names with `_t` at the end are reserved by POSIX. So better not use them for your own types.